# How to change title on entry Documentation page?

Tags: support, feature-request, documentation

On https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scons/topics we have `scons` in title, while ideally it should be named `SCons`. How to change that?

Comment: Ask someone with the “Tag Wiki Edit” privilege to change the “Friendly Name.”

Comment: @JF and how to do this? I can't just plain message everyone with 20000+ reputation.

Comment: Then ask to be able to suggest changes to the friendly names.

Comment: @JF, but where should I ask about it?

Comment: Try asking here on meta.

Comment: @JF, ok, I'll just wait for somebody with "Tag Wiki Edit" privilege to note this question. =)

Comment: @JF, this here already looks a lot like a question.

Comment: Noticed and fixed ;)