# Automatically Title Case all Documentation Pages?

Tags: feature-request, documentation, title

I noticed while skimming the documentation pages that my [favourite programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/topics) isn't in *Title Case*, like the other pages:

[image]

---

This is [relatively easy to fix for a single page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334771/how-to-change-title-on-entry-documentation-page), but difficult if there are a few dozen out there.

Upon looking at some of the topics underneath it, the same issue persists on a scale that is far too large to be solved by anything short than an army of mods, and that would never truly be fixed:

[image]

---

Could it be a good idea, for neatness, consistency, and good formatting's sake, that all such titles are automatically converted to *Title Case*?

Of course, there would be exceptions that are not affected, such as:

1. Articles, conjunctions, and prepositions (*"the", "and", "in"*)
2. Words with symbols (*"std::shared_ptr"*)
3. Words with other capitals (*"iOS", "jQuery"*)
4. (Optional) Words not in the English language (*"typedef", "strlen"*)

Alternately, there could simply be a warning notification when a title is typed that is not in *Title Case*.

Comment: I think replacing *std::shared_ptr* with *Std::shared_ptr* would be a mistake, for example.

Comment: Of course - It wouldn't have to be for every single page, exceptions could be added.

Comment: You're requesting automatic conversion.  I don't really see a point in that if there's going to be an opt-out; it's just going to annoy and confuse users who don't understand why Docs is messing with their input unless they tick that opt-out checkbox.  I agree consistency would be nice, but I think that requires humans agreeing on a style guide and editing to maintain it.

Comment: FWIW, I changed it to *"C Language"* for consistency with the other ones.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this idea poses a few concerns that would make it a bad change to implement.

First, it's unexpected. Users will not necessarily understand what is happening, and requiring users to override it or opt out makes it that much harder to add or edit content.

Second, there are too many exceptions. In addition to all the exceptions you have already identified, there are many others. For example, what about words that *are* in the English language, but have special meaning or are case-sensitive, like `bash`, `float`, `include`, `print`, `string`, etc., depending on the technology in question? Making this automated means either (1) accepting a super-high false-positive rate or (2) an incredible amount of work for the developers to handle all the edge cases.

Third, and most importantly, we don't really need it. You wrote,

> Upon looking at some of the topics underneath it, the same issue persists on a scale that is far too large to be solved by anything short than an army of mods, and that would never truly be fixed.

We *have* an army of people who can make or at least suggest edits: literally every user of the site. If something is bad enough to require correction, then users can fix it or, when necessary, flag it for moderator attention. That system works just fine for things like spelling, capitalization, and punctuation in the Q&As. There's no reason to implement a special system just for Documentation.

Comment: You make a good argument - I'll concede my point. I'm glad we discussed it (though the downvotes still kind of hurt my feelings)

Comment: Always feel free to bring up questions here, and don't worry about downvotes on Meta. They're different from downvotes on the main site and just indicate disagreement.

Comment: Yep, I like how they have a different meaning here. Cheers for the response.

Comment: Also, let's not forget that the Title Case convention is [only that, a localized convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Headings_and_publication_titles) and is not a rule - it's not even that commonly used as a convention these days outside of press headlines.

Comment: [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) is a good example.

Comment: @PeterMortensen agreed. I just didn't list it in my answer because it's already mentioned in the question.